# FFTW and Qt QAudioProbe: Working example?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, real-time, fftw

I'm stuck. Have been searching a while now, tried several different approaches and the best thing I found in the end was an example of Qt (Spectrum), but it's too complex for me to reduce it to what I need:

The goal is real-time audio processing, more specifically applying FFT to visualize it in a bar figure.

This is my code (snippet from a worker class of a QThread):

```
//initialize the recording
void Worker::process() {
    QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
    settings.setCodec("audio/PCM");
    settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);
    settings.setChannelCount(2);

    QAudioRecorder* recorder = new QAudioRecorder(this);
    recorder->setEncodingSettings(settings);

    QAudioProbe* probe = new QAudioProbe();
    probe->setSource(recorder);
    connect(probe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), this, SLOT(onAudioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)));
    recorder->record();
}

//process chunks of audio stream data
void Worker::onAudioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer buffer) {
    int n = buffer.frameCount();
    double *data = buffer.data<double>();

    double x[n];
    fftw_complex y[n];

    //apply Hann Window to data to account for artifacts
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        double hannWindow = 0.5 * (1 - cos((2 * M_PI * i) / (n - 1)));
        x[i] = hannWindow*data[i];
    }

    fftw_plan myPlan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(n, x, y, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(myPlan);

    //sum result into 44 bins for visualization
    int steps = n/44;
    std::vector<double> bins;
    for (int i=0; i<44; i++) {
        double bin = 0;
        for (int q=0; q<steps; q++) {
            //calculate amplitude = sqrt(re*re+im*im)
            double amplitude = sqrt(y[i*steps+q][0]*y[i*steps+q][0]+y[i*steps+q][1]*y[i*steps+q][1]);
            //overwrite NaN with 0. Got a lot of them apparently, without these two lines it crashes immediatly, I guess somewhere downstream
            if (amplitude != amplitude) bin += 0;
            //convert to dB
            else bin += 20*log10(amplitude);
        }
        bins.push_back(bin);
        qDebug() << bins[i];
    }
}
```

I'm working with Qt 5.10, C++ and FFTW.
The problem is that I only get a bunch of NaN, -inf and 0 in the output of the qDebug line, also the input from QAudioBuffer seem to be very low numbers (around e-300). I honestly cannot come up with what is wrong, I have too less understanding of Qt yet, and it's the first time using FFTW and I don't really know how the numbers should look like. Can you find the bug? My goal is to get numbers between 0-1, or something good to handle, to visualize them in a simple plot.

Comment: Have you checked that `x` contains valid time domain data prior to the FFT, i.e. no `NaN`s ?

Comment: `x`also contains NaN, but even when I exclude those by `if (x[i] != x[i]) x[i] = 0;` I get +/-inf and NaN in the output. Also the values in `x` are super small (e.g. 1.18082e-320). Is that the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you need to break this down into smaller more manageable chunks. Forget the FFT for now and concentrate on getting reliable audio input so that you have sensible data in your input buffer. Once you have that working you can start work on the window function, FFT, etc.

Comment: I artificially upscaled the raw input by taking the log and scaling it with respect to the maximum value... just to see what happens. It *seems* to work, although I cannot really assess since due to the new calculations the visual signal is very flickery. How can I get proper signal directly from the AudioBuffer? Some different encoder settings? The documentation as well as my understanding is really poor here unfortunately...

Comment: OK, I optimized the rescaling of the input a bit and now it looks wonderful. A bit dirty solution but it works. Thanks for the hint!